# Avoid excessive data duplication between microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I need some advice in implementing a microservices arhitecture. I have two microservices, one microservie A that contains some catalogs entites shared across multiple microservices and another microservice B that uses a lot of catalogs (more than 10) in one entity. My first approach was to duplicate data from A to B but I think this isn't best solution because I have a lot of duplicated data and I don't know how to keep it synchronized.

I'm using postgresql and java with spring boot for all microservices. My problem is that I need to filter and sort data from A.

How can I avoid data duplication or overhead from syncronizing data between microservices?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "catalogs entities"? Your custom entity or?

Comment: Custom entities that are shared between microservices